# Open pdf in new tab with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf, appendto

I've the following code working properly which opens a pdf downoloaded in the same window:

```
jQuery('<form action="'+ url +'" method="'+ (method||'post') +'">'+inputs+'</form>')
    .appendTo('body').submit().remove();
```

I'd like open the pdf in a new tab or window.. How can I change the appendTo in order to achieve it?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set [target="_blank"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#attr-target)

```
jQuery('<form target="_blank" action="' + url + '" method="' + (method || 'post') + '">' + inputs + '</form>')
  .appendTo('body').submit().remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

Add target='_blank' attribute into forms.

```
target="_blank"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use $.ajax or $.post to get pdf url and you can use window.open() to open this url in new tab:)